# Does Akka Http respect jvmproxy settings?

Tags: akka, akka-http

we are testing our application using Akka Http to use proxy. We would rather not want code change and so we went with global JVM options of http.proxyHost and http.socksProxyHost.
But, we get java.net.NoRouteToHostException errors when accessing accessing through proxy.
Question, Does Akka Http respects global JVM proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the akka-http source code mentions `proxyHost` except for two instances where it's set as a local variable to demonstrate defining a transport which will go through a proxy.

From that, it seems most likely that Akka HTTP doesn't use the JVM proxy settings and if routing through a proxy, you would change code to do that.